# Batch: I need some fresh eyes to see where the error is

Tags: batch-file, command, dos, timed, operand

I keep getting a **Missing operand** error. I cant seem to find it and I figure a new set of eyes can.

```
@echo off

title Log Split And Backup

rem dt = date
rem tm = time
rem wd = week day
rem mh = month
rem dy = day
rem yr = year
rem hh = hour
rem mm = minute
rem ss = second
rem ms = milisecond
rem gtr = greater than
rem lss = less than
rem equ = equal to

echo Starting Log Split And Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 >nul
cls
echo Log Split And Backup Has Started...

:time
set hh=%tm:~0,2%
set mm=%tm:~3,2%
set ss=%tm:~5,2%
set ms=%tm:~7,2%
goto date

:date
set dt=%date%
set tm=%time%
set wd=%dt:~0,3%
set mh=%dt:~4,2%
set dy=%dt:~6,2%
set yr=%dt:~8,4%
goto scheduletimes

:scheduletimes
:hour1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 6 goto minutes1
goto hour2
:minutes1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 0 goto seconds1
goto hour2
:seconds1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% lss 10 goto day1
goto hour2
:hour2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 18 goto minutes2
goto time
:minutes2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 0 goto seconds2
goto time
:seconds2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% lss 10 goto day2
goto time

:days
:day1
for %%i in (Mon) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto mon1
)
for %%i in (Tue) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto tue1
)
for %%i in (Wed) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto wed1
)
for %%i in (Thu) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto thu1
)
for %%i in (Fri) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto fri1
)
for %%i in (Sat) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto sat1
)
for %%i in (Sun) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto sun1
)

:day2
for %%i in (Mon) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto mon2
)
for %%i in (Tue) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto tue2
)
for %%i in (Wed) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto wed2
)
for %%i in (Thu) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto thu2
)
for %%i in (Fri) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto fri2
)
for %%i in (Sat) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto sat2
)
for %%i in (Sun) do (
    if "%wd%"=="%%i" goto sun2
)

:logsplitting
:mon1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\0-mon\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y               
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:tue1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\1-tue\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:wed1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\2-wed\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:thu1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\3-thu\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:fri1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\4-fri\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:sat1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\5-sat\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:sun1
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\6-sun\server1.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:mon2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\0-mon\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:tue2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\1-tue\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:wed2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\2-wed\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:thu2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\3-thu\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:fri2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\4-fri\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:sat2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\5-sat\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
:sun2
@echo %date%
@echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\6-sun\server2.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
```

Thank you to anyone that looked through this entire code and especially thank you to the person that finds the error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the above code is your complete program, then `tm` variable has not been assigned before it is used. I think that this line:

```
set tm=%time%
```

needs to be moved below `:time` label...

Comment: Thank you very much. Yea I am blind lol. I have the set `tm=%time%` under date. I rewrote and switched the time section and date section around and that is what must have caused the error. I new a new set of eyes could fix my problem.

Comment: That fixed the overall **Missing Operand** errors, but now there seems to be another where after it executes the command at the time and the seconds reach outside the window, i'm getting a **Missing Operand** still. I narrowed it down to this line: `:minutes1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%mm%") do set /a MM=%%b
if %MM% equ 0 goto seconds1
goto hour2` 
(it is different because i made the posted code not work for people who don't know how to code, so they can not to steal it) According to the log it isn't setting the **MM** to **%mm%**, since **MM** isn't set, it spits that error.

Comment: The question for this new error can be found at [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621363/batch-during-my-code-loop-it-stops-setting-a-variable-all-help-welcome).
This gives you more info about the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

In essence this code should replace your repetitive code, and also provide a set of robust time and date variables (zero padded) using Wmic (XP Pro and later).

This uses the variables `%var%` and `%server%` in the xcopy routine.

Your `:scheduletimes` routine looks wacky because you seem to be setting and resetting a variable called `%hh%` and are testing the same variable again and again.

If you provide information about the schedule times then that may be simplified too.

```
@echo off

title Log Split And Backup

rem wd = week day
rem mh = month
rem dy = day
rem yr = year
rem hh = hour
rem mm = minute
rem ss = second
rem ms = milisecond
rem gtr = greater than
rem lss = less than
rem equ = equal to

echo Starting Log Split And Backup...
ping -n 1 localhost >nul
cls
echo Log Split And Backup Has Started...

:time
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set Yr=%dt:~0,4%
set Mh=%dt:~4,2%
set Dy=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set MM=%dt:~10,2%
set SS=%dt:~12,2%
set MS=%dt:~15,2%

:date
set dt=%date%
set wd=%dt:~0,3%


:scheduletimes
:hour1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 6 goto minutes1
goto hour2
:minutes1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 0 goto seconds1
goto hour2
:seconds1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% lss 10 set server=server1
goto hour2
:hour2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 18 goto minutes2
goto time
:minutes2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% equ 0 goto seconds2
goto time
:seconds2
for /f "tokens=1*delims=0" %%a in ("$0%hh%") do set /a HH=%%b
if %HH% lss 10 set server=server2

    if "%wd%"=="MON" set var=0-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="TUE" set var=1-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="WED" set var=2-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="THU" set var=3-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="FRI" set var=4-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="SAT" set var=5-%wd%
    if "%wd%"=="SUN" set var=6-%wd%

:logsplitting

echo %date%
echo %time%
echo Starting the 12hr Log Split and Log Backup...
ping -n 1 localhost >nul
xcopy "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt" "C:\Users\Kratos\Dropbox\Minecraft Backups\Logs\%var%\%server%.txt" /D /E /R /I /K /Y               
del "C:\Users\Kratos\Desktop\MC Server\server.txt"
echo Finished Log Split and Log Backup...
goto time
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can see your error by using debug.
Please do as following:

```
> bash -x script1.sh
```

Please look at the following url for more detail.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Comment: I don't think that bash could debug a Batch file ;-)

Comment: From the look of things this is def useless as it does not seem to be for a batch file.